# 9 Bit Floating Point to Hex

Tags: floating-point, binary, hex, decimal, bit

I've been running into an issue where I'm trying to convert a 9-bit floating point number to hex, where the floating point scheme is 1 sign-bit, followed by 4 bit exponent, and then a 4-bit mantissa. Bias is -7.

For example, I have the number -2.5, which in this 9-bit binary scheme would be 1-1000-0100. If I wanted to represent this as a hex, how would I do that?

I was thinking that we left pad the number with 0s, to get 0001-1000-0100 which is 0x184, but in doing so wouldn't I lose the sign?